# Format controlled input using PyInquirer

Tags: python-3.x, windows, terminal

I want to create a script that uses a time input from the user. At the moment I am using [PyInquirer](https://github.com/CITGuru/PyInquirer) because it looks cool but I am not sure if it is capable of doing what I need.

The first prompt asks the user to choose Duration or Time like so:
[image]

If the user then chooses Time the next prompt looks as follows:
[image]

Here the input must only have the default format of HH:MM [AM/PM] where values can only be selected by using the up and down arrows or typed. The cursor must ignore and skip the ':'.

Therefore, the HH and MM may be typed or spinned using the up and down arrow keys and the AM/PM are spinned as well. If typing the HH and MM the cursor must automatically skip the colon.

Here is my code so far:

```
from PyInquirer import prompt, print_json

typeQ = [
    {
        'type' : 'list',
        'name' : 'type',
        'message' : 'Duration or Time based?',
        'choices' : [
            'Duration',
            'Time'
        ]
    }
]

time = [
    {
        'type' : 'input',
        'name' : 'time',
        'message' : 'Specify time:'
    }
]

typeA = prompt(typeQ)
if (typeA == 'Duration'):
    pass
else:
    time = prompt(time)
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example how to use pythons curses library with arrows as key input in a while loop. The mytime() method is only accessed via the arrow key strokes. Some additional keys are also added such you can play with it. See "**#**" for inline comments.

Please post next time your example code and what you've tried fist which is behind the screens you show in the question. Its sailing a little blind without code. If included it would make life easier to anticipate on what structure you use. It also helps up-voting your question instead of people down-voting it due to so-called lack of effort.

Now you have what I've posted and possibly you have to retrofit it to work for your own code. It was a fun morning exercise. Enjoy.

```
import curses, sys, time, re

screen = curses.initscr()

curses.curs_set(0)
screen.keypad(True)
curses.noecho()

regex_time = re.compile('[0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9]')  # time expression selection key.

def mytime():

    screen.addstr("\nTime entry please + [enter]. Input format is [HH:mm].\n")

    event = screen.getstr(5)  # use (0, 0, 15) for location of input string top left in cmd window.

    if regex_time.match(event.decode()):
        screen.addstr("\n You entry = %s h.\n\n >> Add code to do something else here << \n\n" % event.decode())
        screen.refresh()
        time.sleep(2)

        # do something else goes here.

    else:
        screen.addstr('\nDid not receive time\nTry again next round.\n')
        screen.refresh()
        time.sleep(2)

        # do something else goes here.


while True:

    try:
        screen.addstr("Press a key\n")
        curses.echo()
        event = screen.getch()  # get single character

        screen.refresh()

        if event == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            screen.addstr("Left Arrow Key pressed\n")
            screen.refresh()
            time.sleep(0.5)

            mytime()

        elif event == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            screen.addstr("Right Arrow Key pressed\n")
            screen.refresh()
            time.sleep(2)

        elif event == 81:  # 'Q' for quite program.

            curses.echo() # shows which char you pressed.
            screen.addstr('\nThe Quite key "%s" was pressed\n' % (event))
            screen.refresh()
            time.sleep(3)
            break

        else:
            # keystroke identification except for above and regular expression that are comform time annotation.

            curses.echo() # shows which char you pressed.
            screen.addstr('\nThe key "%s" was pressed\n' % (event))
            time.sleep(2)
            screen.refresh()

    except Exception as err:
#        continue
        print (err)

# below code could replace the break in the quite elif statement.
screen.addstr("\nExit program.\n")
screen.refresh()
time.sleep(3)
curses.endwin()
```

Comment: Okay, this is my bad. I did not explain properly. I've edited my question if you wouldn't mind

Comment: You have to post your code that you've tried so far. This prevents reinventing the wheel again and we can see where it goes wrong with your attempt. Looking at PyInquirer it seems possible. You're looking for spinnerbox-like functions. This is easily coded in PyQt5 (GUI).

Comment: That is true!! I've started some PyQt5 tutorials and completely forgot that it turns all the GUI elements to code that I can then adapt to my needs!! Thank you. I'll mark your question as the answer due to this comment